# Getting "This page does not contain any regions that are editable in safe mode" on ALL non-master pages

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Designer 2013, I'm getting the following error when attempting to edit *any page* on the site (other than a master page):

"This page does not contain any regions that are editable in safe mode. Do you want to open this page in advanced mode?"

This includes pages with WebPartZones; even those regions are completely blocked off from editing. As an example, I created a blank Web Part page in SPD, and this is the result immediately after opening it (and declining to use advanced mode):

[image: A brand new Web Part page with a non-editable WebPartZone]

I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: Any update I've got the same problem?